# PHP Mail not reaching the destination on Amazon EC2

Tags: php, email, amazon-ec2, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to send an email using PHP's `mail()` function from a server on `Amazon EC2`. The function is returning `true` but the email is not reaching the destination. I researched on the topic and tried to set up `sendmail` and `sendmail-cf` but didn't solve the issue. Here is the code:

```
$EmailTo = ...; //destination email
$Subject = "New Message Received.";
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Subject: ";
$Body .= $msg_subject;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

try{
     $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);
     echo $success;
}catch(Exception $e){
     echo "Something went wrong. Please try again.";
}
```

All variables are taken from the `$_POST` request from a form and are validated.

Any tip is appreciated.

Comment: It is a complicated topic. Many mail servers no longer accept emails from IPs that are not marked as email servers and that meet a whole list of conditions to protect themselves from spam.

Comment: @MaxMuster I tried to edit the mail system files to add the mail server but did not work. What do you suggest in such a situation?

Comment: Have you checked spam folder in your mail inbox?

Comment: @TufailAhmad yes i did. nothing there.

Comment: Once I had the same issue. putting from (sending mail address) in mail() fixed my problem. You can try.

Comment: Is this different from the code above?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the php mail() function you can use PHPMailer class which is probably the best option as it also runs without a local mail server (Integrated SMTP support).

You can install it via `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer` or download it from here https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer .You can read more about it at the same link.

Here is a simple script for example.

```
require 'vendor\autoload.php'; // For composer

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';  // If you are 
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';  // downloading it without
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';       // composer then include these.

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

try 
{
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp1.example.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    // Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: Can you explain *how* this would solve their problem?